# How to show all of my data usage as tethering?

Tags: root-access, tethering

I have a 50 GB tethering package but I want to use it on my phone too. My carrier said I can't use this package from a Windows phone. Probably because Windows phones don't support their check method. My Mi 9T Pro is rooted so I can change several configurations within the system. Can I mark all of my data transfer as tethered so I can use it on my phone as well?